# React + Redux & initial request configuration

Tags: react-redux

I'm working on React+Redux application and i stuck with some app initialization problems, so i wanna ask:

How to make initial setup for application, e.g. where to set default request headers for communication with api?

Lets assume i have some requestManager module which is not react component.
And it's king of proxy, it adds proper headers for every request.
But in case of user log out and log in i need to set proper token in header.

How to accomplish that?
Can not-react component listen for store events?

What are best practices for that?
Are there some good examples?

Answer (score 0):

It you are using webpack. It has Define plugin which you can declare once and use in every .js file anytime

if you have not experience with webpack

https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#6-feature-flags

In webpack configuration.

```
var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
        "API_HOST": "localhost:3001",
        "API_TOKEN": "my-token"
    }
})
```

In js file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) { // Yep, just call like that
   //Whatever
   console.log(process.env.API_TOKEN) // print out "my-token"
}
```